# Isometry $f:M\to M$ has a fixed point $p$ with $df_p=\text{id} \Rightarrow f=\text{id}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

I'm trying to prove whether or not the following statement is true:

> If $(M,g)$ is a connected Riemannian manifold and $f:M\to M$ is an isometry, then $f=\text{id}_M\Leftrightarrow $ there is some $p\in M$ with $f(p)=p$ and $df_p=\text{id}$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ is obvious.

For $(\Leftarrow)$, I know how to prove it when $(M,g)$ is complete: for any $q\in M$ there is a geodesic $\gamma$ joining $p,q$. Since $f$ is an isometry, $f\circ\gamma$ is a geodesic starting at $f\circ\gamma(0)=f(p)=p$ with velocity $(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=df_p(\gamma'(0))=\gamma'(0)$ so $f\circ\gamma=\gamma$ by uniqueness of geodesics. In particular, $f(q)=q$, which means $f=\text{id}_M$ since $q$ is arbitrary.

For the general case, I don't know how to prove it or find a counterexample.

Comment: It is true. For the other implication, prove that $C=\{q\in M | f(q)=q, T_q f = Id_{T_q M}\}$ is both open, closed and nonempty. For the openness, use that if $q\in C$, then $f \circ \exp_q = \exp_{f(q)} \circ T_q f = \exp_q \circ  T_q f=\exp_q$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the manifold is connected, the goal is to show that the agreement set $$A = \{p \in M \mid f(p) = p \quad\mbox{and}\quad {\rm d}f_p = {\rm Id}_{T_pM}\}$$is non-empty, open, and closed. It is non-empty by assumption. Closed by smoothness of $f$ (which implies continuity of $f$ and of its differential). It remains to show that $A$ is open. So let $p \in A$, and let $D_p\subseteq T_pM$ be an open and starshaped domain for which $\exp_p\colon D_p \to \exp_p[D_p]\subseteq M$ is a diffeomorphism. Then $p \in \exp_p[D_p]$ is open, and we can show that $\exp_p[D_p] \subseteq A$.

If $q \in \exp_p[D_p]$, there is $v \in D_p$ such that the geodesic segment $\gamma\colon [0,1] \to M$ given by $\gamma(t) = \exp_p(tv)$ always lies inside $\exp_p[D_p]$, with $\gamma(1) =q$. By the uniqueness argument you mentioned yourself, we have that $f\circ \gamma = \gamma$. This in particular shows that $f(q) = q$. But since $f$ is an isometry, we have that

$$ f\circ \exp_p = \exp_{f(p)} \circ \,{\rm d}f_p\implies f \circ \exp_p = \exp_q.$$Differentiating at $0$ and using that ${\rm d}(\exp_p)_0 = {\rm Id}_{T_pM}$ and ${\rm d}(\exp_q)_0 = {\rm Id}_{T_qM}$ gives that ${\rm d}f_q={\rm Id}_{T_qM}$ as well.

---

The real consequence here is that if you have two isometries $f,\widetilde{f}\colon M \to M'$ between (connected) pseudo-Riemannian manifolds (positiveness of the metric was irrelevant here), then if there is $p \in M$ with $f(p) = \widetilde{f}(p)$ and ${\rm d}f_p = {\rm d}\widetilde{f}_p$, we conclude that $f=\widetilde{f}$.

The result remains true if we replace "isometries" by "pseudo-Riemannian submersions", provided that the fundamental tensors associated to both submersions are also equal (that's the price one pays for freeing themselves of the dimension constraint). See the paper [The Fundamental Equations of a Submersion](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028999604), by Barrett O'Neill.

Comment: Can you give the details on "Differentiating at $0$ and using that ${\rm d}(\exp_p)_0 = {\rm Id}_{T_pM}$ and ${\rm d}(\exp_q)_0 = {\rm Id}_{T_qM}$ gives that ${\rm d}f_q={\rm Id}_{T_qM}$ as well."? I'd really appreciate it!!!