# Embedding the group of Isometries of a Riemannian manifold to prove that Iso(M,g) is a finite dimensional lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

**The main question is to prove that Isometries of a Riemannian manifold = Iso(M,g) form a finite dimensional Lie group.**

I can use one of the following methods to prove it:

*Method 1) Showing that that an isometry fixing a point p in M such that df at p is identity, must be the identity map. Now use this to define a map from Iso(M,g) to M x TM x ... x TM and show that it is an embedding*

*Method 2) For a point p in M, choose a neighbouhood U of zero in $T_p$M on which the exponential map is a diffeomorphism. Choose a basis {$v_1, v_2, ..v_n$} of $T_p$M that lies in U and show that any isometry  f:M $\rightarrow$ M is determined by f(p) and f(exp$(v_i)$). This determines a map from Iso(M) to M x (M ... x M). Show this is an embedding*

I have been able to solve the first parts of both the methods, but am stuck in the second part(s). My proofs are:-

> **Method 2 Proof**
>
> First we prove that isometry $f: M \rightarrow M$ then $f \circ exp_p = exp_{f(p)} \circ df_p
> $
>
> *Subproof:* Let $A_p$ be the domain of $\mathrm{exp}_{p}$, that is, $A_p$ be the open subset of the tangent space $T_{p}M$ such that : $ A_p = \lbrace v \in T_{p}M, \; \gamma_{v}(1) \; \text{exists} \rbrace $ where $\gamma_{v}$ is the *unique* maximal geodesic of $M$ with initial conditions: $\gamma_{v}(0) = p$ and $\dot{\gamma_{v}}(0) = v$. .
>
> Let $p \in M$ and $v \in A_p$. Since $f$ is an isometry, it is *distance-preserving* and it sends geodesics of $M$ onto geodesics of $M$. This is true as let $f$ be an isometry between Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N,h).$ Then $f$ also preserves the induced metrics $d_1, d_2$ on $M, N$ from $g, h$ resp. that is, $d_1(x,y)=d_2(f(x),f(y))$ for $x,y \in M.$ Then, $f$ sends geodesics on $M$ to geodesics on $N,$ using the length minimizing property of geodesics and that $f$ is distance-preserving. in this case both M and N are the same, as are the induced metrics.
>
> Hence,  $\lambda\ : t \ \mapsto \ f\big( \mathrm{exp}_{p}(tv) \big)$  is a geodesic of M. It satisfies :
>
> $\lambda(0) = f(p)$ and $\dot{\lambda}(0) = df(p)(v)$. The curve $t \mapsto \mathrm{exp}_{f(p)}\big( tdf(p)(v) \big)$ is another geodesic of $M$ which satisfies the same set of initial conditions. we know that geosdesics thus are unique and hence these are the same.
>
> Using the above statement we can prove that local isometries of a connected manifold are completely determined by their values and differentials at a single point, that is, if $\phi, \psi$ : M $\rightarrow$ N are local isometries and p is a point in M such that $d\phi_p$=$d\psi_p$ (and hence $\phi$(p)=$\psi$(p) ), then $\phi = \psi$
>
> *Subproof:* Let $A_q$ = {q $\epsilon$ M : $d\phi_p$=$d\psi_p$}.  By continuity, A is closed in M.
>   Since A is nonempty it suffices to show that A is open. We assert that if q $\epsilon$ $A_q$
>   then any normal neighborhood $U$ of q is contained in A. If r $\epsilon$ $U$ there is a
>   vector v $\epsilon$ $T_q$M such that $\gamma_v$( 1) = $exp_q$(v) = r. Hence $\phi(r) = \phi(\gamma_v(1)) = \gamma_{d\phi v}(1) = \gamma_{d\psi v}(1) = \psi(\gamma_v(1)) = \psi(r) $. Thus $\phi = \psi$ on $U$ and hence $d\phi_r = \psi_r$ for all r $\epsilon$ $U$

**Method 1** proof is relatively simpler and is given on a previous answer, ***and I would personally prefer to solve the main problem using this method 1***: [Isometry $f:M\to M$ has a fixed point $p$ with $df_p=\text{id} \Rightarrow f=\text{id}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467310/isometry-fm-to-m-has-a-fixed-point-p-with-df-p-textid-rightarrow-f-te?rq=1)

**So I am stuck in the second part of either method which is to use the proofs to define maps which would be an embedding of Iso(M) in M x TM x.... TM or M x (M x ... M) respectively.** As I am unsure as to how to understand the concept of an embedding w.r.t isometry group, a complete proof which shows that the defined map (whatever it may be) is indeed an embedding, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Let $n$ be the dimension of $M$. Given what you've already done in Method 1, defining the embedding 
$$F : \text{Iso}(M,g) \to M \times (TM)^n
$$
is pretty straight forward: choose $p \in M$, choose a basis of its tangent space $v_1,...,v_n \in T_p M$, and define
$$F(p) = (f(p), D_p f(v_1), \ldots, D_p f(v_n))
$$
You can then use that to derive the formula for the embedding in Method 2, however you should to make sure that you choose $v_1,...,v_n$ to be contained in a small enough ball around the origin of the vector space $T_p M$ so that the exponential map is defined on that ball.

---

**Added:** You have emphasized your interest in the issue of $F$ being an "embedding". This can be a vague term, and your post does not resolve the vagueness, so there's not too much to be said definitively.

On the set theoretic level, one would certainly start with

> $F$ is an injective function...

That is the only level on which I have addressed your question, although I leave the proof of injectivity for you.

But, perhaps one would want to continue on to topological level with

> ...which is a homeomorphism onto its image...

For that, one needs a topology on the domain which is $\text{Iso}(M,g)$, which has not been specified. Hopefully that's not too much of a problem, for instance perhaps that can be achieved using the compact open topology on $\text{Iso}(M,g)$, so let me assume that has been accomplished.

Next, perhaps one would want to continue on to the smooth level with

> ... and is a diffeomorphism onto its image...

However, serious trouble is beginning to rear its ugly head. For instance, how do we even know that $\text{Iso}(M,g)$ is a smooth manifold? This, of course, is a key issue of your "main question".

At this stage, with so many vaguenesses yet unresolved, I would be afraid to go on to the next level, i.e. the Riemannian level:

> ... and is an isometry onto its image...

Here I honestly do not know what to suggest, because there are quite large unresolved issues. Assuming $\text{Iso}(M,g)$ is indeed a smooth manifold, what Riemannian metric on it do you wish to use? And is there some kind of Riemannian metric you want to use on $M \times (TM)^n$?

Comment: I'm having a bit of confusion with regards to the "embedding" aspect of the group of Isometries. As it must be that metric is preserved, for any two isometries lets say f and h, we must have that <dF(f),dF(h)> in the riemannian metric g, is the same as.... (?)

Comment: I have added some comments to address the "embedding" aspect.

Comment: The smooth manifold aspect is indeed not easy. The shortest proof I know is in the following paper: http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/autmor00.pdf